# Frame-by-frame h.265 transcoding

Tags: handbrake, h.265

I'm capturing 240 FPS footage from the Go Pro Hero 6 Black in a lab setting, and I need to be able to review the footage frame by frame.

Right now, I'm attempting to transcode the h.265 video output (from the go pro) using "HandBrake" so that I can open it in a free video editor (DaVinci Resolve). I have tried toying around with the handbrake settings, specifically changing "Framerate" (in the video tab) to "same as source", but have had no success.

I'm not tied to any software or method, I just need to view the 240 FPS footage frame-by-frame somehow. My boss would prefer a way of doing this without paying for any software licenses, but obviously employee time has a cost too so if a method requiring paid software is much faster, then so be it.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is currently happening when you try this?

Comment: AFAIK, Handbrake won't allow you to conform the framerate i.e. keep all frames but retime them.  If you're ok with a commandline tool, ffmpeg can do it.

Comment: Currently the transcoder outputs ~24 fps video (i.e. when I import the clip to DaVinci resolve and step through frame by frame, I get around 24 fps). I'm using 240 FPS footage of a millisecond-accurate stopwatch to verify this result.

I will check out ffmpeg, thank you for the tip!